# list item change color on hover, not when nested span is hovered over

Tags: css

I have a nested `span` in a `li` element. I want the color of the `li` only to change when it is hovered over. However

```
#sortable li:hover:not(.ce){
  background-color:#3f0;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

does not work. The li changes color when my cursor is over the span as well. How can I make the `li` only change color when it --and not the span-- is hovered over?

http://jsbin.com/alExeVO/16/edit

Comment: Are you trying to change the background color of LI or the foreground text color?

Comment: @NickKarnik good point. background color

Comment: In that case, you should use: 

#sortable li:hover{
  color:red;
  cursor:pointer;
}

Answer (score 0):

As your `<span>` is part of the `<li>` your code behaves as expected. A hack would be to add a hover to your span so it changes to the original color.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `span` and the `li` their own hover features. Check it out.

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/HtfaQ/)

```
ul{
list-style-type:circle;
text-align:center;
}
ul li{
   display:inline-block;
border:1px solid purple;
padding:20px;
}
ul li span{
font-size:2em;
}
ul li:hover{
background:orange;
}
ul li span:hover{
background:white;
color:black;
}
```